# Saucelab: Get webdriver code from manual test

Tags: c#, automated-tests, saucelabs, manual-testing

I've set up a demo account with Saucelabs.
There are two kinds of tests, manual and automated.
With the manual tests you can use a recorder to set up the test, with the automated you use your own code to contact Saucelabs and have them run your custom code/tests.

Is there a way to get the code ( C# code if possible ) from the manual test so that it can be used as a starting point for automated tests. This could greatly reduce the time needed to setup the automated tests as most ids/selectors will already be available.

Any comments and feedback are welcome.

Comment: What are you trying to test? Are you using Sauce Labs as your CI or as service to test across different browsers?

Answer (score 0):

The Firefox browser has a [SeleniumIDE](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) plugin, which allows you hit a "record" button and then do actions in a website and save the steps recorded out as C#, Java or other languages.

SauceLabs themselves have also built a tool, based on SeleniumIDE called [SauceIDE](https://saucelabs.com/blog/ridiculously-easy-cross-browser-testing-with-sauce-ide).

The code emitted can act as a starting point.